# how to display latest six posts on home page (Laravel 5.5)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm want to display latest 6 posts on my homepage.Here I'm using Laravel and Javascript. but I'm getting the layout in different way. How can I display those things here. Any idea. Thanks in Advance.

### post.blade.php

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-lg-4">

    <h2>{{$article->title}}</h2>

    {{ $article->created_at->toFormattedDateString() }}

    <p>{{$article->body}} </p>

    <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>

  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4">

    <h2>{{$article->title}}</h2>

    {{ $article->created_at->toFormattedDateString() }}

    <p>{{$article->body}} </p>

    <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>

  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4">

    <h2>{{$article->title}}</h2>

    {{ $article->created_at->toFormattedDateString() }}

    <p>{{$article->body}}</p>

    <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>

  </div>

</div>
```

### index.blade.php

```
@extends('master')

@section('content')


<div class="container">

    @foreach ($article as $article)

      @include('article.post')

    @endforeach

</div>

@endsection
```

### View

I want to display like view in a pattern but i'm getting a duplicate data. how can i rectify that
[View pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCmXI.png)

Comment: `foreach ($article as $article) ...?`

Comment: use foreach in `article.post` instead of using in `index.blade.php`

Answer (score 0):

Please try these

```
$acticle->orderby('created_at', 'DESC')->take(6)->get()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the field id in table acticle is autoincrement,try this

```
$acticle->orderby('id', 'DESC')->take(6)->get()
```